# Is the for i in range used correctly in my python code?

Tags: python

I'm new to python coding at the moment I'm doing some while/for/if exercises to learn how it works. I copied below one of the codes I prepared that is working fine except it prints out the number at which current_position = target_position and statement "Target achieved" instead just the "Target achieved". How can I change it so it prints out all the values of current_position util it is equal to target position and then "Target achieved".

```
current_position = 0

jump_value = int(input("Enter the jump number :"))
target_position = int(input("Enter the target number :"))

while current_position != target_position:
    for i in range(0,1):
        current_position = current_position + jump_value
        if current_position >= 100:
            current_position = current_position % 100
        print("You are at:", current_position)
        if current_position == target_position:
            print("Target achieved")
    if current_position == 0:
        print("Target not found", target_position)
        break
```

Comment: `for i in range(0,1)` will never be a usefull code, because there is only 1 iteration

Comment: there's no need for a for loop here. you only did 1 iteration.. just add the value you want to current_position and keep the if statements